# How to fix the error of this message script developed in Python?

Tags: python, udp, connection, chat, message

I'm breaking my head with this script in Python.

My goal is to send message back and forth, and for testing I am trying to run both files on the same machine, but the message does not arrive at the other end.

Here's the code:

- send.py:

```
import socket
import random
import time

def calculate_checksum(segment):
    checksum = sum(segment) & 0xFFFF
    return checksum.to_bytes(2, "big")

def send_segment(segment, address, sock):
    if random.random() < 0.2:
        return

    time.sleep(1.0)

    sock.sendto(segment, address)

def send_message(message, sock, address):
    segments = [message[i:i+1400] for i in range(0, len(message), 1400)]

    estimated_rtt = 1.0
    dev_rtt = 0.0

    for segment in segments:
        checksum = calculate_checksum(segment.encode())
        segment_with_checksum = segment.encode() + checksum

        send_segment(segment_with_checksum, address, sock)

        start_time = time.time()

        while True:
            try:
                ack, _ = sock.recvfrom(1400)
                if ack == segment_with_checksum:
                    rtt = time.time() - start_time
                    dev_rtt = 0.75 * dev_rtt + 0.25 * abs(rtt - estimated_rtt)
                    estimated_rtt = 0.875 * estimated_rtt + 0.125 * rtt
                    break
            except socket.timeout:
                timeout = estimated_rtt + 4 * dev_rtt

                if time.time() - start_time > timeout:
                    send_segment(segment_with_checksum, address, sock)
        sock.close()

def send_chat():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind(("localhost", 12345))

    sock.settimeout(1.0)

    recipient_address = input("IP: ")

    recipient_port = int(input("Port: "))
    recipient = (recipient_address, recipient_port)

    while True:
        message = input("Message ('quit' to quit): ")
        if message.lower() == "quit":
            break

        send_message(message, sock, recipient)

    sock.close()

send_chat()
```

Now, the another script (reeciver)...

- receive.py:

```
import socket

def receive_message(sock):
    message = ""

    while True:
        segment, address = sock.recvfrom(1400)
        segment_data = segment[:-2]

        if segment_data[-1] == "$":
            message += segment_data[:-1].decode()
            break

        message += segment_data.decode()

    return message

def send_ack(segment, address, sock):
    sock.sendto(segment[-2:], address)

def receive_chat():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind(("localhost", 54321))

    sock.settimeout(10.0)

    while True:
        try:
            segment, address = sock.recvfrom(1400)

            received_checksum = int.from_bytes(segment[-2:], "big")
            segment_data = segment[:-2]
            calculated_checksum = sum(segment_data) & 0xFFFF

            if received_checksum == calculated_checksum:
                send_ack(segment, address, sock)
                if segment_data[-1] == "$":
                    received_message = segment_data[:-1].decode()
                    print("Mensagem recebida:", received_message)
            else:
                print("Erro!")
                continue

        except socket.timeout:
            print("Timeout!")
            continue
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break

    sock.close()

receive_chat()
```

Would you know what the problem is?

I would like to send message from one end to the other but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

### Fixed code

**send.py**

```py
import socket
import random
import time

def calculate_checksum(segment):
    checksum = sum(segment) & 0xFFFF
    return checksum.to_bytes(2, "big")

def send_segment(segment, address, sock):
    if random.random() < 0.2:
        return

    time.sleep(1.0)

    sock.sendto(segment, address)

def send_message(message, sock, address):
    segments = [message[i:i+1400] for i in range(0, len(message), 1400)]

    estimated_rtt = 1.0
    dev_rtt = 0.0

    for segment in segments:
        checksum = calculate_checksum(segment)
        segment_with_checksum = segment + checksum

        send_segment(segment_with_checksum, address, sock)

        start_time = time.time()

        while True:
            try:
                ack, _ = sock.recvfrom(1400)
                if ack == segment_with_checksum:
                    rtt = time.time() - start_time
                    dev_rtt = 0.75 * dev_rtt + 0.25 * abs(rtt - estimated_rtt)
                    estimated_rtt = 0.875 * estimated_rtt + 0.125 * rtt
                    break
            except socket.timeout:
                timeout = estimated_rtt + 4 * dev_rtt

                if time.time() - start_time > timeout:
                    send_segment(segment_with_checksum, address, sock)
    
    sock.close()

def send_chat():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind(("localhost", 12345))

    sock.settimeout(1.0)

    recipient_address = input("IP: ")
    recipient_port = int(input("Port: "))
    recipient = (recipient_address, recipient_port)

    while True:
        message = input("Message ('quit' to quit): ")
        if message.lower() == "quit":
            break

        send_message(message, sock, recipient)

    sock.close()

send_chat()
```

**receive.py**

```py
import socket

def receive_message(sock):
    message = ""

    while True:
        segment, address = sock.recvfrom(1400)
        segment_data = segment[:-2]

        if segment_data[-1] == "$":
            message += segment_data[:-1].decode()
            break

        message += segment_data.decode()

    return message

def send_ack(segment, address, sock):
    sock.sendto(segment[-2:], address)

def receive_chat():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind(("localhost", 12345))

    sock.settimeout(10.0)

    while True:
        try:
            segment, address = sock.recvfrom(1400)

            received_checksum = int.from_bytes(segment[-2:], "big") & 0xFFFF
            segment_data = segment[:-2]
            calculated_checksum = sum(segment_data) & 0xFFFF

            if received_checksum == calculated_checksum:
                if segment_data[-1] == "$":
                    received_message = segment_data[:-1].decode()
                    print("Mensagem recebida:", received_message)
                send_ack(segment, address, sock)
            else:
                print("Erro!")
                continue

        except socket.timeout:
            print("Timeout!")
            continue
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break

    sock.close()

receive_chat()
```

### Explanation

> Where you went wrong

1. **Mismatched Ports**: In your `send.py` script, you bind the socket to port 12345, but in the `receive.py` script, you bind the socket to port 54321. Make sure both scripts are using the same port number.
2. **Socket Closure**: In the `send_message` function of `send.py`, you are closing the socket after sending the first segment. Since the socket is closed, subsequent segments cannot be sent. Move the line `sock.close()` outside the for loop, so the socket is closed only after all segments have been sent.
3. **Checksum Calculation**: In the `calculate_checksum` function of `send.py`, you are passing the segment as a string to `encode()`. However, in the `receive.py` script, you are treating the received segment as bytes. Update the `calculate_checksum` function in `send.py` to take bytes as input instead of a string. Change `segment.encode()` to `segment`.
4. **Checksum Comparison**: In the `receive_chat` function of `receive.py`, you compare the received checksum (`received_checksum`) with the calculated checksum (`calculated_checksum`). However, the calculated checksum is the sum of the segment bytes, while the received checksum is the last two bytes of the segment. To compare them correctly, you need to convert the last two bytes of the segment to an integer before comparison. Modify the line `received_checksum = int.from_bytes(segment[-2:], "big")` to `received_checksum = int.from_bytes(segment[-2:], "big") & 0xFFFF`.
5. **Acknowledgment**: In the `receive_chat` function of `receive.py`, you are sending the acknowledgment (`send_ack`) for each segment received. However, the acknowledgment should be sent only after the checksum has been verified. Move the line `send_ack(segment, address, sock)` inside the `if received_checksum == calculated_checksum` block.

**PS:** Make sure to run both scripts in separate terminals or command prompt windows. One running send.py and the other running receive.py.

Comment: Hey, @Advik. Tks!

I tried with the changes, but it gives the following error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

I think it's because segment is String and checksum is bytes, that is, I would have to transform the String into bytes, no?

Comment: Okay I will fix this as soon as possible